# create continuous payperiod for everymonth

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to create a continuous payperiod for every month . suppose i was insert a payperiod for last jan that is start date : 01-01-2012 12:00:00 enddate : 30:01:2012 11:59:00 Transaction date : 31:01:2012 12:00:00 and status : OPEN . Now i want the below result based on the above entry that is

```
 2. start date : 01-02-2012 12:00:00 enddate : 28:02:2012 11:59:00 Transaction date : 29:02:2012 12:00:00 and status : CLOSED
 3. start date : 01-03-2012 12:00:00 enddate : 30:03:2012 11:59:00 Transaction date : 31:03:2012 12:00:00 and status : OPEN
```

and the first status OPEN changed to CLOSE. This process continuous automatically based on first entry start,end and transaction date please help me  to do this...

Comment: What do you expect to happen in February (especially on leap years)?

Comment: you can get the first day of the month, search a bit and you will find how to get the last day of a month, your end date is one day less than the last day, based on these try out something and if you get stuck in something concrete, you can come back here !

Comment: The above result created automatically for each month starts or reach transaction date..

Comment: So what is that you want to achieve, its not clear, maybe you could edit the post and make it more relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code below

```
public class Result
{
    private int _daysInMonth;
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public ResultCollection Generate(DateTime fromdate, DateTime enddate)
    {
        var collection = new ResultCollection();
        for (; fromdate < enddate; fromdate = fromdate.AddMonths(1))
        {
            _daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(fromdate.Year, fromdate.Month);
            var res = new Result
                             {
                                 StartDate = fromdate,
                                 EndDate = fromdate.AddDays(_daysInMonth - 1).AddMinutes(-1),
                                 TransactionDate = fromdate.AddDays(_daysInMonth - 1),
                                 Status = "Close"
                             };
            collection.Add(res);
        }
        collection.ElementAt(collection.Count-1).Status = "Open";
        return collection;
    }
}

public class ResultCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Result>
{
}
```

Call the function using

```
 DateTime start = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01);
 DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 05, 01);
 GridView1.DataSource = new Result().Generate(start, end);
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

I hope this helps !!!